# Static function in PHP only sometimes returns an error (Illegal Offset Type)?

Tags: php, function

Here a function that I modified a little to decode bencoded files.

```
# decode a bencoded string
public static function decode($s, &$pos = 0) {
    if($pos >= strlen($s)) {
        return false;
    }
    switch($s[$pos]) {
        case 'd':
            ++$pos;
            $retval = array();
            while(isset($s[$pos]) && $s[$pos] != 'e') {
                $key = self::decode($s, $pos);
                $val = self::decode($s, $pos);
                if($key == false || $val == false) {
                    break;
                }
                $retval[$key] = $val; // ERROR OCCURES HERE
            }
            $retval['isDct'] = true;
            ++$pos;
            return $retval;
        case 'l':
            ++$pos;
            $retval = array();
            while(isset($s[$pos]) && $s[$pos] != 'e') {
                $val = self::decode($s, $pos);
                if($val == false) {
                    break;
                }
                $retval[] = $val;
            }
            ++$pos;
            return $retval;
        case 'i':
            ++$pos;
            $digits = strpos($s, 'e', $pos) - $pos;
            $val = (int)substr($s, $pos, $digits);
            $pos += $digits + 1;
            return $val;
        default:
            $digits = strpos($s, ':', $pos) - $pos;
            if($digits < 0 || $digits > 20) {
                return false;
            }
            $len = (int)substr($s, $pos, $digits);
            $pos += $digits + 1;
            $str = substr($s, $pos, $len);
            $pos += $len;
            return (string)$str;
    }
    return false;
}
```

You will notice that I have commented where the error occures it says;

`Illegal offset type`

I do not know how this is happening though as before assigning `$retval[$key] = $val` I check to see if either value is false first and if it is then break from the switch statement.

Like I said this only happens probably once every 50 attempts at decoding bencoded strings.

Any one know how I could fix this or what is causing it?

Answer (score 2):

`$key` has to be a string (or able to be juggled into one). Any other type and it will throw that error. You're checking for bool `false` which is good, but it could also be `true, null, object, array`, etc.

Comment: Thanks for this, I just assumed that as the function can only return `false` then that is all it could be as it is called recursively.

Comment: @Mike B +1 for the avatar! War never changes!